# Computing the percent of authorship in a Google document?

Tags: google-docs, collaboration, statistics

I have a Google document where 4 people contributed. Is there any way to get a sense of how much each of them committed, like [TortoiseSVN does for SVN repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23406956/395857)?

[image]